# Enable/Disable button - Verify username existence

Tags: ajax, button

I'm trying to verify the existence of username in DB.

I have one field that contains a text field and a submit button. The submit button is disabled.

Once the user enters a valid username and after checking in the DB, the submit button becomes enabled and the text field border turns to green, or else to red.

Just here all is fine, but when the user changes his mind and tries to change the username, the submit button is still enabled despite the text field indicates a wrong username or format.

How can I change the submit button to disabled.

I tried in my code this `document.getElementById('register').disabled = false;`

[image]

This is the full code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#username').keyup(username_check);
}); 
function username_check()
{   
var username = $('#username').val();
if(username == "" || username.length < 14)
{
    $('#username').css('border', '2px #CCC solid');
    $('#tick').hide();
}
else
{
jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "check.php",
   data: 'username='+ username,
   cache: false,
   success: function(response){
    if(response == 1){
        $('#username').css('border', '2px #C33 solid'); 
        $('#tick').hide();
        $('#cross').fadeIn();
        document.getElementById('register').disabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        $('#username').css('border', '2px #090 solid');
        $('#cross').hide();
        $('#tick').fadeIn();
        document.getElementById('register').disabled = false;
     }

}
});
}
}
</script>
<style>
#username
{
    padding:3px;
    font-size:18px;
    border:3px #CCC solid;
}
#tick{display:none}
#cross{display:none}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<form action="" method="get" style="width:500px">
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="152">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="348">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Username</td>
    <td><input name="username" id="username" type="text" />
          <img id="tick" src="tick.png" width="16" height="16"/>
          <img id="cross" src="cross.png" width="16" height="16"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="register" id="register" value="Submit" disabled="disabled" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("#register").attr("disabled","disabled") in success and $("#register").removeAttr("disabled") in failure...

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Remove `document.getElementById('register').disabled = true;` from success function of jQuery.ajax call.

And modify the keyup event as:

```
$('#username').keyup(function()
{
document.getElementById('register').disabled = true;
username_check();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('register').disabled = true;
```

it will work